# MySQL left join to get last messages and usernames

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get all user names and last_messages with who the current user had conversation.

I have two tables:

**Thread**

[image]

**User**

[image: id, name]

So, if current user's id is 1, I should get rows for bob and mike, but I get empty result. Could you please help me to find the mistake.

```
SELECT * FROM thread
LEFT JOIN user
ON ((thread.user1_id!=current_user AND thread.user1_id=user.id) 
    OR (thread.user2_id!=current_user AND thread.user2_id=user.id))
WHERE current_user = 1;
```

Comment: SQL Server? MySql? Oracle?  What DBMS?

Comment: Your query would return no rows when `current_user` is not `1`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ab85c/1 - obviously(?) just join the names table at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    calls.*
from User
left join (
    select
        User.Name, thread.user2_id as Partner_id 
    from User join thread on thread.user1_id = user.id
    union all
    select
        User.Name, thread.user1_id as Partner_id
    from User join thread on thread.user2_id = user.id
) calls
on calls.partner_id = User.id
where User.id = 1
```

Note how the double join from thread to User is done - once against both sides of the call in the subquery as an inner join, then a second time as outer table of an outer join.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'Partner_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @EducateYourself: Corrected to match your change in RDBMS specification from SQL-SERVER to MySQL

Comment: I got usernames and partner ids, but I should get thread_id and last_message from thread table, and usernames from user table

Comment: Besides, there's an awful lot of query here

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this way

```
SELECT * FROM thread t
LEFT JOIN user u1
ON t.user1_id = u1.id
LEFT JOIN user u2
ON t.user2_id = u2.id
where t.user1_id = '1' or t.user2_id = '1'
```

should get rows for bob and mike (Thread row 1 & 2 )

Comment: But it's not very discerning